# Wait until Code behind WPF Animation is Completed

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, animation, wait

I am building an application that looks like [RoboZZle](http://www.robozzle.com) , but I have a problem:(the programming language in the answer is not important : C# or VB.NET)
I have three animations in the code behind which look like this:

```
Private Sub btngo_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btngo.Click
        go_stright()
        go_stright()
        go_stright()
        go_stright()
End Sub
Private Sub go_stright()
        Dim da As New DoubleAnimation()
        Dim tt As New TranslateTransform()
        da.From = offsety
        offsety -= 50
        da.To = offsety
        da.Duration = New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        tt.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, da)
End Sub
```

This is the problem: when I click the "btngo" button, the last animation (4th go_stright) has animation effect. I need to wait until one animation is completed before the next one starts.
How can I do this?
**Note:** In roboZZle , the user with his algorithm moves sprite to destination and sprite movement isn't pre-defined. 
i am a newbie in WPF.
**Update:** I have no Story Boards.
**Update 2**:My XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="Level1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="Level1" Width="794" Height="535" Loaded="Page_Loaded_1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="735*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="69*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="m1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" Height="54" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <Button.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="m2" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" Height="54" Margin="69,1,0,0">
            <Button.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightColorKey}}"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="m3" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" Height="54" Margin="128,1,0,0">
            <Button.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightColorKey}}"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="m4" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" Height="54" Margin="187,1,0,0">
            <Button.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightColorKey}}"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="m5" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" Height="54" Margin="246,0,0,0">
            <Button.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightColorKey}}"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="m6" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" Height="54" Margin="305,0,0,0">
            <Button.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="215,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="215,149,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="215,199,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="215,249,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="215,299,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="264,299,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="314,299,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="364,299,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="413,299,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="413,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="413,149,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="413,199,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="413,249,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="264,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="314,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="364,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50">
            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
            </Rectangle.Stroke>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/l1khoone.png" Stretch="None"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Ellipse x:Name="g1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="228,313,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF005DFF" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
        <Button Content="" x:Name="btnup" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="54" Height="54" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Margin="721,48,19,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button.Foreground>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/up.jpg" Stretch="None">
                    <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                            <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                            <RotateTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </ImageBrush>
            </Button.Foreground>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/up.jpg"/>
            </Button.Background>

        </Button>
        <Button Content="" x:Name="btnleft" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="54" Height="54" Margin="721,107,19,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button.Foreground>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/up.jpg" Stretch="None"/>
            </Button.Foreground>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/left.jpg"/>
            </Button.Background>

        </Button>
        <Button Content="" x:Name="btnright" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="54" Height="54" Margin="721,166,19,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button.Foreground>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/up.jpg" Stretch="None"/>
            </Button.Foreground>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Right.jpg"/>
            </Button.Background>

        </Button>
        <Button Content="" x:Name="btnf1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="54" Height="54" Margin="721,225,19,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button.Foreground>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/up.jpg" Stretch="None"/>
            </Button.Foreground>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/F1.jpg"/>
            </Button.Background>

        </Button>
        <Button Content="" x:Name="btnf2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="54" Height="54" Margin="721,284,19,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsEnabled="False">
            <Button.Foreground>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/up.jpg" Stretch="None"/>
            </Button.Foreground>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/F2.jpg"/>
            </Button.Background>

        </Button>
        <Button Content="GO!" x:Name="btngo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="54" Height="54" Margin="721,343,19,0" Background="Red" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Meiryo" FontSize="19" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button Content="Reset" x:Name="btnreset" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="54" Height="54" Margin="721,402,19,0" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Meiryo" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Cyan" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Ellipse x:Name="g2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="427,313,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF005DFF" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
        <Ellipse x:Name="g3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="427,112,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF005DFF" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
        <Image x:Name="sprite" Margin="215,100,461,320" Source="Images/downsprite.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: EventHandler(OnAnimationCompleted)?

Comment: @Smartis I am a newbie to WPF.Speak more please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a completed event on the animation in which you will check how many steps you have to make and perform them if you're not there yet:

```
Private Sub btngo_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    PerformNextAction(actions(0))
End Sub

Private Sub go_stright()
    Dim da As New DoubleAnimation(offsety, offsety - 50, New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
    offsety -= 50
    Dim tt As New TranslateTransform()
    AddHandler da.Completed, AddressOf AnimationCompleted
    tt.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, da)
End Sub

Private Sub AnimationCompleted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If actionCounter < 4 Then
        actionCounter += 1
        PerformNextAction(actions(actionCounter))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PerformNextAction(ByVal action As Action)
    Select Case action
        Case MainWindow.Action.GoStraight
            go_stright()
        Case MainWindow.Action.RotateLeft
            rotate_left()
        Case MainWindow.Action.RotateRight
            rotate_right()
    End Select
End Sub
```

Don't forget this one too:

```
Private goStraightCounter As Integer
```

This one will keep track of your progress (how many times you need to keep calling the method).

**Edit**
To answer your comment, you could make an enum like this:

```
Public Enum Action
    GoStraight
    RotateRight
    RotateLeft
End Enum
```

In the application you linked, the user has to make a list of action, so you could make that list a list of action (see enum). Then, instead of calling "go_stright", you just look at the next entry in the action list and call the method that goes for that action.

**Edit 2:**
To go deeper on actions, make a list of actions:

```
Public actions As ObservableCollection(Of Action)
```

So if the user has 5 actions he picked, you would have 5 enumactions in your list. So the list might look like this for example: GoStraight, RotateLeft,  GoStraight, RotateLeft, GoStraight. In the animationcompleted event, instead of just calling the go_straight, you could implement a select case that checks which method you have to call (see updated code above). I just guessed how your go left and go right methods are called, so you might have to change those names.

Comment: Doesn't Work! AnimationCompleted Didn't run

Comment: Does the animation do what you want it to do (move something on the UI)?

Comment: da.completed isn't fire.and sprite goes straight one time of three times.

Comment: Please speak more about enum action.What about "F1" in enum action?

Comment: Can you provide some XAML, so I can try more here?

Comment: @SepehrMohammadi: I changed the answer, I forgot I had to add the handler before beginning the animation. See my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Register an new EventHandler for the Completed Event in C#:

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation ani = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation();
            ani.Completed += new EventHandler(ani_Completed);
        }

        void ani_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. Wire up a completed event and a property, then use a method that clears the dispatcher thread before returning..

```
// at the end of animation routine
progressTransition.Completed += new EventHandler(progressFlyOut_Completed);
progressTransition.Begin(ControlElement);
// allow animation to complete
WaitForCompletion(seconds * 2);

// completion event
private static void progressFlyOut_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AnimationCompleted = true;
}

    // wait routine
    private static void WaitForCompletion(double TimeOut)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        while (AnimationCompleted == false)
        {
            if (stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > TimeOut)
                break;
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() => { })).Wait();
        }
        AnimationCompleted = false;
    }
```